# User in docker can't create folders and files

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, hanami

I have a problem with creating folders and files within a docker container. I have a Ruby and Hanami web app deployed using Dockerfile and docker-compose yaml. Here is the content of both files for reference.

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM ruby:2.7.5-bullseye

    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install vim -y

    RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

    RUN adduser --disabled-login app_owner

    USER app_owner

    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    COPY --chown=app_owner Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
    COPY --chown=app_owner . ./

    RUN gem install bundler:1.17.3
    RUN bundle install

    ENV HANAMI_HOST=0.0.0.0
    ENV HANAMI_ENV=production

    EXPOSE 2300
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - 5432
    volumes: 
      - postgres_staging:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: >
      bash -c "bundle exec hanami db migrate
      && bundle exec rake initial_settings:add_default_language
      && bundle exec rake initial_settings:add_session_validity
      && bundle exec rake import_user:create
      && bundle exec rake super_admin:create
      && bundle exec rake create_parser_rules:start
      && bundle exec hanami assets precompile
      && cp -r apps/myapp/assets/webfonts public/webfonts
      && cp -r apps/myapp/assets/webfonts public/assets/webfonts
      && cp -r apps/myapp/assets/images/sort*.png public/assets
      && cp -r apps/myapp/assets/images/sort*.png public
      && cp -r apps/myapp/assets/images/ui-icons*.png public/assets/wordrocket
      && mkdir public/assets/images
      && cp -r apps/myapp/assets/images/sort*.png public/assets/images
      && bundle exec hanami server"
    volumes:
      - ./hanami_log:/usr/src/app/hanami_log
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_staging:
  web:
  nginx:
```

The docker-compose has some initial commands that need to be run and the ones creating folders and files are failing. For example `bundle exec hanami assets precompile` fails with: `Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/src/app/public`

The command created the folder and then copies over some files. I've confirmed this error by omitting the command from docker-compose and then tried running the command manually in the running container. I get the same error.

Is my configuration incorrect?

EDIT: **Forgot one important thing: the problem occurs on the client's server running Ubuntu 20.04, while it works without issues on my dev laptop.**

Thank you.
Seba

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a answer, but after some more digging I see that this is actually a correct behavior. And I should take care of this before building the image. I need to move those commands (apart from precompile, which will work when the public folder exists) for creating folders and files out of the compose and run them before building.

Comment: Also, it's working on my laptop because those folders and files already exists, but are in the gitignore and as such are not available on the server.